# Full Text Search SQL has different effect between ios8 and ios7

Tags: ios, sqlite, fmdb

I have use the "*" symbols to do selecting on ios7 sqlite which the effect what i want, but ios8 sqlite does not supporting "*" and show "no result". Is the FMDB problem or the ios 8 does not support the "*" symbols?

SQL(with FMDB):

```
db.executeStatements("create virtual table if not exists TABLE_1 using fts3(col_1,Result)")    
db.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM TABLE_1 WHERE col_1 MATCH ?",withArgumentsInArray:["*A*"])
```

Table:

```
    +==============================+
    |     Name: TABLE_1            |
    +------------------------------+
    |   col_1     |     Result     |
    +==============================+
    |     A       |      result 1  |
    +------------------------------+
    |     B       |      result 2  |
    +------------------------------+
    |     AAB     |      result 3  |
    +------------------------------+
```

Comment: Use percentage instead? `withArgumentsInArray:["%A%"])`

Comment: i have used, but not the effect of ios 7.

Comment: The ios8 does not support "\*A\*", but support "A\*", ha.

Comment: if i implement on chinese which cannot search correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS 8 does not support `"*A*"`, but does support `"A*"`:

```
db.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM TABLE_1 WHERE col_1 MATCH ?",withArgumentsInArray:["A*"])
```